# Activity used to start app doesn't exist (Cannot open Calculator app in Android 5.1.1)

Tags: java, android, appium

I'm really new to Appium so excuse me if its a repeat question. But, I'm trying to run some tests on the calculator app on Android 5.1.1 using Appium and it results in the following error.

> error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Activity
>   used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it
>   exists and is a launchable activity
>
> info: [debug] Error: Activity used to start app doesn't exist or
>   cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity

Test Code (capabilities):

```
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "SecCalculator2");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator.Calculator");
```

I have downloaded the 'APK info' app on my phone and this app shows the following info.

APK path: `/system/app/SecCalculator2/SecCalculator2.apk`

Activities: `com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator.Calculator`

So am I using the correct package and activity names in the capabilities?

Thanks in advance

Comment: One small suggestion , copy this apk to your system, don't provide appPackage & appActivity capabilities . Only mention path to this apk. Hope it will work .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add app file name in desired capabilities like below:

```
capabilities.setCapability("app", "/system/app/SecCalculator2/SecCalculator2.apk");
```

Also you can skip to add "appPackage" and "appActivity" Appium automatically launch application which is mentioned in apk file.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can correct the appPackage as following :

```
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator");
```

*Assuming mostly the activity names are prefixed with the package name.*

**Edit** : Your logs read incorrect activity name. So probably sometimes the name is provided using a `/` which would also be mentioned in the appium server logs.