# Appium-Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity

Tags: android, android-emulator, appium

I am trying to run a test file created on eclipse using appium. When I execute the test on a real android device connected to the system, I get the following error:

Encountered internal error running the command:

> Error: Error occurred while starting App.
>
> Original error: Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity.

The app opens fine manually and on the emulator so I'm not sure what's the issue with real devices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity used to start app doesn't exist (Cannot open Calculator app in Android 5.1.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383008/activity-used-to-start-app-doesnt-exist-cannot-open-calculator-app-in-android)

Comment: The answers on that thread did not work for me.

Answer (score 14):

The issue speaks for itself: you either **did not provide activity to recognise your app** or you **specified the wrong one**.

What you can do:

1. Connect device to laptop, make sure adb debugging is on
2. Install your app manually and launch it
3. In terminal run:

`adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'`

4. Check the output, you will get something like:

`com.yourcompany.package/com.yourcompany.package.login.view.LoginActivity`

So now you have package - `com.yourcompany.package` and activity `com.yourcompany.package.login.view.LoginActivity` that you should provide Appium.

5. Add new capabilities, full set should look like:

   `DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
   capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "device");
   capabilities.setCapability("app", pathToApk);
   capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "android");
   capabilities.setCapability("appWaitPackage", "com.yourcompany.package");
   capabilities.setCapability("appWaitActivity", "com.yourcompany.package.login.view.LoginActivity");`

Works perfectly for me on multiple real devices

Answer (score 0):

Check manually Your app like @dmle said,

1. Open app on Android
2. go to terminal, console, command line (whatever)
3. Adb should be installed,
4. input in termninal
   `adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp`

The command will provide current package & activity.

Maybe developers changed You package id.

Answer (score 0):

I always received "Encountered internal error running command: Error: The application at " "does not exist or is not accessible" I user a `Driver wait` and  it solved.

Answer (score -1):

I follow the guide [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md)

1. Type the following command to Terminal(not execute yet)

   `adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'`
2. Manually open app on device and execute the above command really quick to find the startActivity.
3. Copy value of Package and Activity from mFocusedApp=
4. Check the Activity start-able

   `adb shell am start -n package.android/.activity.SplashActivity`
5. Set of Capabilities
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

   ```
   capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
   capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy Note9");

   capabilities.setCapability("appWaitPackage", "package.android");
   capabilities.setCapability("appWaitActivity", ".activity.SplashActivity");
   capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "package.android");
   capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".activity.SplashActivity");
   capabilities.setCapability("appWaitDuration", 10000);//this is way optional, 20000 by default

   capabilities.setCapability("app", newApp.getAbsolutePath());
   ```

Comment: You need to remove "appActivity" and "appWaitDuration" Capabilities. In my case I had to remove "app" too as its an already installed app.