# Appium Unknown server-side error occurred - did not start application

Tags: automation, automated-tests, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

I am trying to test a mobile app in appium but its throwing the following error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. 
Original error: Cannot start the 'com.example.abc' application. 
Original error: 'com.example.abc.ui.splash.SplashActivity' or 'com.example.abc.ui.splash.SplashActivity' never started. 

Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting 
(WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Follwing are my capabilities setup

```
    @Before
public void setUp() {
    File f = new File( "src" );
    //App Name
    File fs = new File( f, "app-sandbox-debug.apk" );
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability( "deviceName", "Samsung  SM-A305F/DS Android 10, API 29" );
    capabilities.setCapability( "platformName", "Android" );
    capabilities.setCapability( CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android" );
    capabilities.setCapability("normalizeTagNames","true");
    capabilities.setCapability( MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath() );
    try {
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>( new URL( "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub" ), capabilities );
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
        System.out.println("Application running");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am unable to find the error cause nor unable to find what's missing at my end.

Comment: can you set short device name? you don't need to write api level.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appium-Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360074/appium-activity-used-to-start-app-doesnt-exist-or-cannot-be-launched-make-sure)

Answer (score 1):

You can use adb shell dumpsys window windows command to see the launch activity

1. Launch the app on the device
2. connect the device to PC/Laptop with adb enabled
3. In terminal enter the following command `adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'"`
4. Use the correct activity which can be launched properly